# delete category on plugin deactivation wordpress

Tags: plugin-development, categories, taxonomy

I am trying to delete the category dynamically when the plugin is deactivated but it is not deleting But it is adding on activation properly the only problem is deletion of category on deactivation.

**function to add category**

```
function add_category_on_activation(){
    global $wpdocs_cat_id;
    $wpdocs_cat = array('cat_name' => 'Event Category', 'category_description' => 'An Event Category to show all events', 'category_nicename' => 'events', 'category_parent' => '');
    $wpdocs_cat_id = wp_insert_category($wpdocs_cat);

}
```

**function to delete category**

```
function delete_category_on_deactivation(){

    wp_delete_category($wpdocs_cat_id);

}
```

**Hook to add category**

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, "add_category_on_activation" );
```

**Hook to delete category**

```
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, "delete_category_on_deactivation" );
```

Answer (score 0):

You should save that category id in option table instead of set as global. Try below code which is helps you to delete that category on deactivation hook.

```
function add_category_on_activation(){
    $wpdocs_cat = array('cat_name' => 'Event Category', 'category_description' => 'An Event Category to show all events', 'category_nicename' => 'events', 'category_parent' => '');
    $wpdocs_cat_id = wp_insert_category($wpdocs_cat);
    if($wpdocs_cat_id)
    {
        update_option('wpdocs_cat_id',$wpdocs_cat_id);
    }

}

function delete_category_on_deactivation(){
    $wpdocs_cat_id = get_option('wpdocs_cat_id');
    if($wpdocs_cat_id)
    {
        wp_delete_category($wpdocs_cat_id);
        delete_option('wpdocs_cat_id');
    }

}
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, "add_category_on_activation" );
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, "delete_category_on_deactivation" );
```